# How does Haskell's lens package handle fields that are also keywords?

Tags: haskell, lenses

How does lens handle the case where a de-sugared field is a keyword? I seem to remember reading that something special is done, but I can't remember where I read it or what the name of the "lensed" accessor would end up as.

Consider the following:

```haskell
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import           Control.Lens
import           Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)
import           Data.Maybe
import           Data.Aeson
import           Data.Aeson.TH
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy    as L
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as LC8
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy.Encoding as TLE


data Typ = Typ {
    _fld1 :: BS.ByteString
  , _type :: Int
} deriving (Show)

$(deriveJSON tail ''Typ)
$(makeLenses ''Typ)


main = do
  print $ typ^.fld1
  print $ typ^.getType
  where
    jsonTyp = "{\"fld1\": \"Test\", \"type\": 1 }"
    typ'    = decode jsonTyp  :: Maybe Typ
    typ     = fromJust typ'
    getType :: Getter Typ Int
    getType = to _type
```

What would the `_type` accessor be called and how do I avoid having to implement `getType` here?

I had to bash this out on school of haskell because I don't have access to a proper dev environment here, but I figure it might be useful to others. I'll add an answer when I can drop into ghci and do a `:browse` (if that gives an answer), but in the mean time does anyone know?

### Conclusion

Thanks guys, I'll use `makeLensesWith` along with a mapping of keywords to replacements as per Edward's suggestion.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It doesn't do anything special. The generated lens is named `type` and funnily enough, GHC appears to be totally cool with this. You can even use it if you use the fully qualified name:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}    
module Foo where

import Control.Lens

data Bar = Bar { _type :: String }
  deriving Show

$(makeLenses ''Bar)
```

```
> :l Foo
> :t type      -- Um...
<interactive>:1:1: parse error on input `type'
> :t Foo.type  -- Haha!
Foo.type
  :: (Functor f, Profunctor p) =>
     p String (f String) -> p Bar (f Bar)
> Bar "hello" ^. Foo.type
"hello"
```

Comment: Note that GHC 7.10 is no longer cool with this. You cannot generate lenses with keyword names anymore. See [this issue](https://github.com/tfausak/strive/pull/99) for an example.

Answer (score 6):

I usually just pick a field name that is nearby. Use something like `_ty` instead of `_type` and then the resulting lens will be callable.

You can also use `makeLensesWith` to supply a custom name mangling function.

Comment: Thanks Edward. The problem in this case is that the field names come from the json of a web service (and I'm autogenerating the data declarations)... I suppose I could take the same approach with the From|ToJSON derivation as well.

Comment: So what does lens end up doing in this case? It didn't throw an error in this case, does the `_type` just get dropped?

Comment: It'll make the lens with template haskell, since it constructs the syntax tree directly and doesn't get parsed that works fine. You just can't invoke it without qualification.

Comment: Note: you can also just write the `ty f (Bar a) = Bar <$> f a` lens by hand, and export it.

Comment: I have no idea why it took this long but I just noticed how similar lens construction and `traverse` construction is. Let alone that you explicitly state this similarity on the derivation page AND I've read *Functor is to Lens as Applicative is to Biiplate* AND it's pretty clear that they're related once you start using `Traversal`s. The syntactic parity gets lost when you just use the TH shortcuts, I suppose.